# Jquery "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

i got the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in my jquery code.

code is working perfect on this link when i code it separate check here http://www.test2.guru99.com/career_guide/

but when i placed this code in my joomla website code is not working
check the design it is messed up http://screencast.com/t/EcXh407N40
and  check the link

same code is not working here http://www.test2.guru99.com/best-sap-module.html

Comment: You need to show us some code..

Comment: And what line or line is causing the error.

Comment: Usually that means, that you haven't included jQuery before it gets used.

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...});` use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: Maybe a compatibility error between mootools and jquery

Comment: A. Wolff - $ is alias of jQuery, it does not matter which one u use.

Comment: CorwinCZ in theory you'll be right but in joomla you have jquery and mootools at the same time and use just $ can generate conflicts

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above replace all the $ with jQuery.

So

```
$(document) -> jQuery(document)
$("#domain")-> jQuery("#domain")
```

In addition to that I checked the code in your [demo](http://www.test2.guru99.com/career_guide/) and I really suggest you to do a minimum of caching.

Eg: you repeat everywhere `$("#domain").hide();`  instead cache the in a variable $("#domain") and after use the method hide().

```
 var $domain = jQuery("#domain"); // now the element is cached in $domain

 //now you can use $domain
 $domain.hide();
```